# How does grid-row-start work during CSS3 grid layout?

Tags: css, css-grid

When I apply `grid-row-start: <integer>` to the third grid item, it's placed on the left side of the grid.

When I apply `grid-row-start: span <integer>`, it's not on the left side.

Why is the grid item positioned in a cell on the left when `grid-row-start` is given just an integer?

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ececec;
    grid-template-columns: [col1-st] 1fr [col1-en col2-st] 1fr [col2-en col3-st] 1fr [col3-en];
    grid-template-rows: [row1-li] 1fr [row2-li] 1fr [row3-li] 1fr [row4-li];
}

.container div {
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ececec;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.container .rBg {
    background: #e02323;
}

.container .gridRowStNumber {
    grid-row-start: 1;
}

.container .gridRowStString {
    grid-row-start: row4-li;
}

.container .gridRowStSpan {
    grid-row-start: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>aaa</div>
    <div>bbbb</div>
    <div class="rBg gridRowStNumber">cccccc</div>
    <div>ddd</div>
    <div>eeee</div>
    <div>ff</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#placement):

> The location of a grid item’s grid area within the grid is defined by its placement, which consists of a **grid position** and a **grid span**:

> **grid position**
>
> The grid item’s location in the grid in each axis. A grid position can be either definite (explicitly specified) or automatic (determined by auto-placement).
>
> **grid span**
>
> How many grid tracks the grid item occupies in each axis. A grid item’s grid span is always definite, defaulting to 1 in each axis if it can’t be otherwise determined for that axis.

> The grid-placement properties—the longhands grid-row-start, grid-row-end, grid-column-start, grid-column-end, and their shorthands grid-row, grid-column, and grid-area—allow the author to specify a grid item’s placement by providing any (or none) of the following six pieces of information:

Then if you continue the reading you will see the different cases. To explain using easy words, you have 4 cases

- You specify a number that define *the position* and *the span* will be equal to 1. This is the case where you define `grid-row-start: 1;` which will make the position of the element at the first column.
- You specifiy a number that define *the span* and *the position* will be automatic. This is the case where you define `grid-row-start: span 1;` which will make the element take one column but placed automatically.
- You specify both the position and the span and here you will need to use the `*-start` and `*-end`
- You specify nothing and the position will be automatic and the span equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Specifing `span <integer>` for `grid-row-start` only tells the browser how far the starting and endig edges of the item should be from each other. It doesn't palce it in a row.

You can read about the placement algorithm here: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#auto-placement-algo

In short, were the row specified with `grid-row-start: <integer>`, the algorithm would try to place it in the start-most available column.

For elements with unspecified row and column the algorithm processes them in document-order (by default) and places them in unoccupied cells going left-right top-bottom (agian, by default).

I recommend reading the documentation, if you are interested in the nitty-grity.